# C# Convert datetime to date javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime

I sent a date time from controller using this variable `IncidentReportedDt` the value is : `2016-08-11 09:30:30.287`  to .cshtml and i want to display it by javascript.

if i just manually print this variable `IncidentReportedDt`  : The output is `/Date(1470882630287)/`

then i try some of the following tips :

```
var date3 = IncidentReportedDt.toDate();
var date4 = IncidentReportedDt.ToString();
```

it gives me this output :

```
TypeError: IncidentReportedDt.toDate is not a function
TypeError: IncidentReportedDt.toString is not a function
```

i tried another way using this :

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(IncidentReportedDt));
```

and it's give me an output : `Invalid Date`

so i add this code :

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(IncidentReportedDt));
var dte = date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (date.getUTCDate());
```

and it's give me an output : `NaN/NaN/NaN`

i want the output : `2016-08-11 09:30`.
can you help me what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the following function to convert this date format to JS format:

```
function parseDotNetDate(str) {
    var regexp = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//;
    if (!regexp.test(str)) 
        throw new Error('Not a .NET DateTime object.');

    return new Date(+str.replace(regexp, '$1'));
}
```

Comment: hi yeldar, may i ask what is '$1' function ?

Comment: @Shasapo Hello :) It is a part of `String.prototype.replace` functionality which means "the first captured group in regular expression".